# Image turns black after cropping

Tags: php, jquery, css

I'm trying to add a crop image system for my website. I have downloaded [the jQuery plugin](https://www.webslesson.info/2018/03/source-code-of-image-crop-and-uploading.html) for cropping images.

Everything works very well. The image can be cropped and be sent to its directory and it can be saved on the database the problem is after cropping and moving to the folder it turns into black. I have no idea why it's happening.

Here is my jQuery code

```
$image_crop = $("#image_demo").croppie({
        enableExif:true,
        viewport:{
            width:200,
            height:200,
            type:'square'
        },
        boundary:
        {
            width:300,
            height:300
        }
    });



    $('#profile_image_id').on('change',function(){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(event){
        $image_crop.croppie('bind',{
            url:event.target.result
        }).then(function(){
            console.log('jquery bind complete');
        });
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        $('#modal-profile_pic').modal('show');
    });

    $('.crop_image').click(function(event){
        $image_crop.croppie('result',{
            type:'canvas',
            size:'viewport'
        }).then(function(response){

            $.ajax({
                url:"php/userUpdateData.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{
                    'cropped_image':response
                },success:function(data){
                    $('#modal-profile_pic').modal('hide');
                    $("#profilePicture").html(data);

                }
            });


        })
    });
```

And here is my PHP code

```
if(isset($_POST['cropped_image']))
{
    $imgInfo = $_POST['cropped_image'];
    $imagesPlaces = 'images/'.basename($imgInfo);
    $checkImage = getimagesize($imgInfo);

    if(!$checkImage)
    {
        echo 'it\'s not an image';
    }else
    {
        $image_expl_get = explode(';',$imgInfo);
        $second_image_expl_get = explode(',',$image_expl_get[1]);
        $image_after_codes = base64_decode($second_image_expl_get[1]);
        $profile_pic_name_new = bin2hex(random_bytes(64)).'.png';



         $send = file_put_contents('../user-img/'.$profile_pic_name_new,$image_after_codes);


        $update_my_page_profile_pic = "UPDATE funnylasndusertable SET user_profile_image='$profile_pic_name_new'
        WHERE username='$user_username'";
        $upload_new_private_image = mysqli_query($connect,$update_my_page_profile_pic);




        if($upload_new_private_image)
        {
            if($send)
            {
                echo "<img id='user_pro_pic' class='user_pro_image' src='user-img/$profile_pic_name_new' />";
            }else
            {
                echo 'couldn\'t send the file';
            }


        }else
        {
            echo 'there was an error in uploading image';
        }



    }
```

Another problem is about Range slider. It's too sensitive! If I move it just a little bit the cropper zooms a lot. I find out its class name in the croppie.css is "cr-slider" and in croppie.js on line 607 there are its codes but I couldn't find a way to change its value and make it move smoother.